# Trouble printing odd lines

Tags: java, list, arraylist, bufferedreader

I have the following method that takes lines of string input, adds them to a list and then is meant to first print the even lines, then the odd lines. The problem is is that it only prints the even lines and does not go on to print the odd lines. The solution seems like it would be simple, but I cannot see what would be wrong with my if/else statements that would cause this problem.

```
public static void printLines(BufferedReader r, PrintWriter w) throws IOException {
    //first prints even lines then odd lines
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    int x = 0;
    for (String line = r.readLine(); line != null; line = r.readLine()) {
        list.add(line);
        x++;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++){
        if (i%2 == 0 && x < 1){
            w.println(list.get(i));
            x++;
        }
        else if (i%2 == 1 && x >= 1)
        {
            w.println(list.get(i));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: delete the x variable and use list.size() instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than deal with arithmetic in the loop, have the loop iteration handle it:

```
for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i+=2)
    w.println(list.get(i));
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i+=2)
    w.println(list.get(i));
```

I recommend you delete the x variable and use list.size() instead

Answer (score 1):

Use @Bohemian method. But if you want to make use of your code, just add an else to your for:

```
    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0 && x < 1) {
            w.println(list.get(i));
            x++;
        } else if (i % 2 == 1 && x >= 1) {
            w.println(list.get(i));
        } else{
            i = 0;
            x = 0;
        }
    }
```